# does the memory space of windows and linux overlap for some folders when both operating systems are installed?

Tags: linux

I have both linux and windows installed on my pc.  when I make some programs in lex and yacc (when working on linux)and store all the files  in a folder ,they are corrupted If I use windows for some time. for example 3 days back after storing all the files( xyz.l , a.out ) I switched to windows for some other work after rebooting my pc. after 3 days when I again open that folder(while using linux) a.out was converted into an image and when I double clicked on it, an image opened. the image was same which I downloaded 2 days back while working on windows but I stored in some other folder. so does the memory space used for storage for linux and windows overlap? if not what could be the reasons? It has happened 2 times. and really I have to recode all my programs . I am not able to understand why?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supposed to overlap.This sounds like a configuration problem , where windows and linux are configured to mount the same [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning).
Check the file [/etc/fstab](http://man.cx/fstab) (under linux) and find out whether this is true.You can try making files in various places and observe if they can be found on the other os.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your partitioning looks like, but I guess that it is set up in a way that both OS have read/write access to all partitions, or at least windows has read/write access to the Linux partition.

Is your linux partition a FAT32 partition? You should set it to read only in windows, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Do you use hibernate on the windows side? Windows can get confused if data changes while it is asleep, and this might be the cause of the problems.